# How can I create a timer that counts down, visualizing it on screen, while other procedures are performing? TASM Assembly

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, bios, tasm

I'm creating a game in TASM assembly that is guessing the names of all countries, like [this](https://www.jetpunk.com/quizzes/how-many-countries-can-you-name) one.
I have done everything needed except I'm unsure how to create a countdown timer

I have tried this code, but when I use it other procedures can't be performed:

```
        MOV CX, 3
        MOV DX,1060h
        MOV AH,86h
        INT 15h
```

Comment: I'm thinking you meant [MOV AH, 86h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1525.htm)?

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes

Comment: It's not clear from your question why you need to execute other code while waiting for the timer? But if you _do_ need that then you could achive an asynchronous wait by hooking the timer tick interrupt handler (`1Ch`) with the help of interrupts `21h / ah=35h` and `21h / ah=25h`.

Comment: @Michael I need to execute other code while there is a timer because the timer in the game is showing only how much time left, but the game is still playable, the player writing countries, and the time is ticking down, I don't quite understand what do you mean by hooking the timer tick interrupt handler, do you have a link where I can read more about this?

Comment: _"do you have a link where I can read more about this?"_ Google the interrupts I mentioned in my comment.